# gfsporson problem: Greek text not being displayed in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, greek

I've been working on an article in English, Arabic, Hebrew, and Greek. I've had to switch from pdfLaTeX over the weekend as I realised that Biblatex doesn't work with utf8, so I switched to XeLaTeX.

For the Greek text, I've decided to use the package gfsporson. The problem is that everytime I run the file, the Greek text doesn't show up on the PDF.

I've tried several combinations and permutations, and tried several exmaples on the forum, but none seem to work. When I set the Greek text font to Times New Roman the Greek text shows perfectly (as can be expected), but I prefer the GFS-Porson font so much more.

Here's my code --- perhaps if someone can help me figure this out.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{gfsporson}

\begin{document}

This is an example in Greek:

\textporson{μήτε ἐν ταῖς τελευταίαις μοίραις τῶν ζῳδίων ἐπειδὴ κακοποιοί εἰσιν}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but `gfsporson` is explicitly described as using `LGR` encoding only so is strictly an 8-bit (pdfTeX) font

Answer (score 3):

The OpenType version of GFS Porson should be available on your system.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\babelfont[greek]{rm}{GFSPorson.otf}

\begin{document}

This is an example in Greek:

\foreignlanguage{greek}{μήτε ἐν ταῖς τελευταίαις μοίραις τῶν ζῳδίων ἐπειδὴ κακοποιοί εἰσιν}

\end{document}
```

Don't load `xunicode` or `xltxtra`. They used to be recommended up to a few years ago, but now they may even do harm.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it's finally working! Woohoo! I can't thank you enough.